# organizing analytical file for persons with multiple records

Tags: data-preprocessing

My stakeholders have manually recorded data for patients enrolled in an intervention, which is causing data issues that I need to resolve in order to move to determine what is the appropriate statistical approach.

Each person has a unique medical ID number that can be used. The stakeholders created a field called family ID to indicate which persons are part of the same family. The family ID is given at the time of referral to the program. Person IDs of the same family have different person IDs and share the same family ID. Manually linking families is the only solution we have, as our medical record system cannot do this for us.

Stakeholders want to analyze the data at the family ID level. However, owners of the data file created a system that when a person who was not enrolled in the program and gets re-referred to them receives a new family ID. This creates family IDs that appear unique but contain the same individuals. Additionally, not all persons get included in the new family ID documentation. In truth, this family ID field should really be considered a referral ID.

Example of raw data:

|person ID|referral date|family ID|enrolled date|
|---------|-------------|---------|-------------|
|a|01/01/2022|1|Null|
|b|01/01/2022|1|01/01/2022|
|c|02/01/2022|2|02/01/2022|

If we are to use the family ID as the unit of analysis, with the referral date or enrollment date as the index date, then this creates several data problems:

1. Which family ID actually represents person A and person B?
2. Comparing family ID = 1 and family ID = 2 is comparing person A
3. Depending on the index date used, there will be data loss when we fix the follow-up time

I am sure missing other potential issues.

My recommendation to the team is to adjudicate the first family ID to everyone in that family. So person A and person B will both be family ID = 1. And, assign the first referral date and enrollment date at the person level. A new column can be created at the person level that documents how many family IDs (i.e. referrals) were tracked. Something like this: 
|person ID|referral date|family ID|enrolled date|# of referrals|
|---------|-------------|---------|-------------|--------------|
|a|01/01/2022|1|02/01/2022|2|
|b|01/01/2022|1|01/01/2022|1|

Do you think this is an appropriate way to organize this data so that each family ID correctly has all persons, and is unique?